# GNU MIX Development Kit build error

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

I am trying to compile [the GNU MIX assembly development kit](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mdk/) on Mac OS X 10.8.4. I've installed the dependencies through homebrew, and when I run `configure` in the mdk directory, I get a success message:

```
*** GNU MDK 1.2.7 has been successfully configured. ***

Type 'make' to build the following utilities:
    - mixasm (MIX assembler)
    - mixvm (MIX virtual machine)
```

But when I run `make`, It spits out this error:

```
~/Downloads/mdk-1.2.7 > make
make  all-recursive
Making all in po
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in intl
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in doc
Making all in img
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in lib
rm -f libreplace.a
ar cru libreplace.a
ar: no archive members specified
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
  ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
  ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
  ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
  ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
  ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
  ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
  ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
  ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make[2]: *** [libreplace.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It looks like `ar` is failing, although I don't know why. How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 0):

It is [a bug in mdk](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?41097). It has already been reported to the developers of mdk and fixed, but they have not yet released a new version containing that fix. Hopefully 1.2.8 will be released soon and will not have this problem. If you can't wait, you can get the latest code from their repository and build that.

More specifically, the problem is that they are trying to create a library libreplace.a that contains nothing ("no archive members"), and this is not acceptable to the OS X version of the `ar` program which requires that every library contain something. Why would anyone try to create an empty library? In this case, the library contains compatibility functions which only need to be built if the particular OS version you're on doesn't already provide them. In your case, your operating system already provides all of these functions, so none of the compatibility functions needed to be built. The developer either did not anticipate that such a complete OS would exist, or that there might exist a system on which an empty library was not allowed. [The fix](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/mdk.git/commit/?id=e9ea3e62501814c4224237f6242fed83a1c886cc) was to add an empty function to the library on OS X, to ensure that it is never empty.